# Multiple Tables in Zend based on the Quick Start Guide Example

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am new to Zend and have been attempting to follow the [Zend Quick Start Guide's example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html) of using Data Mappers and extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. I think I've grasped the general concepts, but I am now wondering, how I would go about modifying the guide's example code to allow for multiple tables.

Here is the part of the code I am currently interested in modifying:

```
protected $_dbTable;

public function setDbTable($dbTable)
{
    if (is_string($dbTable)) {
        $dbTable = new $dbTable();
    }
    if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
    }
    $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
    return $this;
}

public function getDbTable()
{
    if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
        $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook');
    }
    return $this->_dbTable;
}
```

I have changed it to this:

```
protected $_dbTables;

public function setDbTable($dbTable, $tableName)
{
    if (is_string($dbTable)) {
        $dbTable = new $dbTable();
    }
    if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
    }
    $this->_dbTables[$tableName] = $dbTable;
    return $this;
}

public function getDbTables()
{
    if (null === $this->_dbTables) {
        $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Courses', 'courses');
        $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_CourseTimes', 'course_times');
    }
    return $this->_dbTables;
}
```

Is this a correct way to go about implementing multiple tables within the Data Mapper pattern or would you do it differently? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I now realise that my logic here was slightly faulty and caused by ignorance of the MVC pattern. My suggested solution in this question is not a good one, as there really should be only one table per mapper. If multiple simultaneous inserts are required they should either be invoked from the Controller or via another model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to return data from related tables, you should either [add queries with joins to one `Zend_Db_Table`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311481/how-to-use-join-in-zend-framework) or use [`Zend_Db_Table_Relationships`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html) to fetch associated data. The benefit of using Joins is that you will only do one query over many when using Relationships. The drawback is that joined tables wont return `Zend_Db_Table_Row` objects (iirc), but since you are going to map them onto your Domain objects anyway, it's not that much of an issue.

Structurally, you can do like I suggested in [How to change Zend_Db_Table name within a Model to insert in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436461/how-to-change-zend-db-table-name-within-a-model-to-insert-in-multiple-tables). Whether you create a Gateway of Gateways or simply aggregate the Table Gateways in the DataMapper directly is really up to you. Just compose them as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about INSERT rather than SELECT statements. Yes they are two related tables. I don't think I could use either of the methods you suggested for this? The docs for Zend_Db_Table_Relationships state, "There is no support for a cascading INSERT. You must insert a row to a parent table in one operation, and insert rows to a dependent table in a separate operation."

Comment: Please check my answer I tell me what you think.

Comment: @Gordon in your accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436461/how-to-change-zend-db-table-name-within-a-model-to-insert-in-multiple-tables) you suggested creating two Zend_Db_Table_Abstract instances, one for each table. Which is actually where I got my initial idea from. Is this because a Data Mapper was not used or are you no longer recommending this method?

Comment: @Azriel Sorry for being unclear. There is nothing wrong with it. You can use it like described in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the best practice, but, this is my abstract mapper:

```
<?php
abstract class Zf_Model_DbTable_Mapper
{
    protected $_db;
    protected $_dbTable = null;

    protected $_systemLogger = null;
    protected $_userLogger = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_systemLogger = Zend_Registry::get('systemLogger');
        $this->_userLogger = Zend_Registry::get('userLogger');

        // Set the adapter
        if(null !== $this->_dbTable)
        {
            $tableName = $this->_dbTable;
            $this->_db = $this->$tableName->getAdapter();
        }
    }

    public function __get($value)
    {
        if(isset($this->$value))
        {
            return $this->$value;
        }

        $dbTable = 'Model_DbTable_' . $value;
        $mapper = 'Model_' . $value;

        if(class_exists($dbTable))
        {
            return new $dbTable;
        }
        elseif(class_exists($mapper))
        {
            return new $mapper; 
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The property, DbTable or Mapper \"$value\" doesn't exists");       
        }
    }

    public function __set($key,$value)
    {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }

    public function getById($id) 
    {
        $resource = $this->getDefaultResource();

        $id = (int)$id;
        $row = $resource->fetchRow('id =' . $id);

        if (!$row) {
            throw new Exception("Count not find row $id");
        }

        return $row;    
    }

    public function getAll() 
    {
        $resource = $this->getDefaultResource();

        return $resource->fetchAll()->toArray();    
    }

    public function save(Zf_Model $Model)
    {
        $dbTable = $this->getDefaultResource();
        $data = $Model->toArray();

        if(false === $data) return false;

        if(false === $Model->isNew())
        {
                if(1 == $dbTable->update($data, 'id =' . (int)$Model->getId()))
                {
                    return $Model;
                }
        }
        else 
        {       
            $id = $dbTable->insert($data);

            if($id)
            {
                $Model->setId($id);
                return $Model;
            } 
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function remove($id)
    {
        return $this->getDefaultResource()->delete('id =' . (int) $id);
    }

    protected function getDefaultResource()
    {
        if(empty($this->_dbTable))
        {
            throw new Exception('The $_dbTable property was not set.');
        }

        $classname = 'Model_DbTable_' . $this->_dbTable;
        if(!class_exists($classname))
        {
            throw new Exception("The Model_DbTable_\"$classname\" class was not found.");
        }


        return new $classname;
    }

    protected function getDefaultModel()
    {
        return current($this->_models); 
    }

    protected function getResources()
    {
        return $this->_resources;
    }
}
```

And this is one for my implemented mappers:

```
<?php
class Model_TwitterPostsMapper extends Zf_Model_DbTable_Mapper
{
    /*
     * Data Source 
     * @var string Zend_Db_Table name
     */
    protected $_dbTable = 'TwitterPosts';

    public function recordExists($Item)
    {
        $row = $this->TwitterPosts->fetchRow($this->TwitterPosts->select()->where('status_id =?', $Item->getSource()->getStatusId()));
        if($row)
        {
            return $row->id;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getLastUpdate($options) 
    {
        $select = $this->TwitterPosts->select()
                       ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                       ->from(array('t' => 'twt_tweets'), 't.created_at')
                       ->join(array('u' => 'twt_users'), 't.user_id = u.id', '')
                       ->order('t.created_at DESC');

        if($options['user_id'])
        {
            $select->where("t.user_id = ?", $options['user_id']);
        }

        if($options['terms'])
        {
            if(is_array($options['terms']))
            {
                $condition = '';
                foreach($options['terms'] as $i => $term)
                {
                    $condition .= ($i > 0) ? ' OR ' : '';   
                    $condition .= $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('content LIKE ?',"%$term%");
                }

                if($condition)
                {
                    $select->where($condition);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->TwitterPosts->fetchRow($select)->created_at;
    }

    public function getSinceId($term = null)
    {
        $select = $this->TwitterPosts->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                       ->from('twt_tweets_content', 'status_id')
                       ->where('MATCH(content) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', "$term")
                       ->order('status_id ASC')
                       ->limit(1);
        //echo $select; exit;

        $tweet = $this->TwitterPosts->fetchRow($select);

        if(null !== $tweet) return $tweet->status_id;

        return 0;
    }

    public function getAllByStatusId($statuses_id)
    {
        $select = $this->TwitterPosts->select()
                       ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                       ->from(array('t' => 'twt_tweets'), array('t.id', 't.user_id', 't.status_id','t.user_id'))
                       ->join(array('u' => 'twt_users'), 't.user_id = u.id', array('u.screen_name', 'u.profile_image'))
                       ->where('status_id IN(?)', $statuses_id);

        $rows = $this->TwitterPosts->fetchAll($select);

        $Posts = array();
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            // Here we populate the models only with the specific method return data
            $data = $row->toArray();

            $Post = new Model_TwitterPost($data['id']);
            $Post->populate($data);

            $User = new Model_TwitterUser($data['user_id']);
            $User->populate($data);

            $Post->setUser($User);
            $Posts[] = $Post;
        }

        return $Posts;
    }

    public function getAllSince($since_id)
    {
        $select = $this->TwitterPosts->select()
                       ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                       ->from(array('t' => 'twt_tweets'), array('t.status_id','t.user_id'))
                       ->join(array('u' => 'twt_users'), 't.user_id = u.id', array('u.screen_name', 'u.profile_image'))
                       ->where('status_id > ?', $since_id)
                       ->order('t.datetime DESC');

        $rows = $this->TwitterPosts->fetchAll($select);

        $Posts = array();
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            // Here we populate the models only with the specific method return data
            // TODO: This is not a truly lazy instatiation, since there's no way to get the not setted properties
            $data = $row->toArray();
            $Post = new Model_TwitterPost($data);
            $User = new Model_TwitterUser($data);
            $Post->setUser($User);
            $Posts[] = $Post;
        }

        return $Posts;
    }

    public function getTotalRatedItems($options)
    {
        $options = $this->prepareOptions($options);

        $select = $this->TwitterPosts->select()
                       ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                       ->from(array('t' => 'twt_tweets'), array('COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS total','r.rate'))
                       ->join(array('u' => 'twt_users'), 't.user_id = u.id', '') 
                       ->join(array('r' => 'twt_tweets_rate'), 't.id = r.tweet_id', array('r.rate'))
                       ->group('r.rate')
                       ->order('t.datetime DESC');

        $select = $this->prepareSelect($select, $options);

        $rates = $this->TwitterPosts->fetchAll($select)->toArray();

        $itemsRated = array('Green' => 0, 'Yellow' => 0, 'Orange' => 0, 'Red' => 0, 'Gray' => 0);
        foreach ($rates as $rate) 
        {
            $itemsRated[$rate['rate']] = $rate['total'];
        }

        return $itemsRated;
    }

    public function getUsersActivity($options)
    {
        $options = $this->prepareOptions($options);

        $select = $this->TwitterPosts->select()
                       ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                       ->from(array('t' => 'twt_tweets'), array('COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS total','DATE(t.datetime) AS datetime'))
                       ->join(array('u' => 'twt_users'), 't.user_id = u.id', '') 
                       ->joinLeft(array('r' => 'twt_tweets_rate'), 't.id = r.tweet_id', '')
                       ->group('t.user_id')
                       ->order('t.datetime DESC');

        $select = $this->prepareSelect($select, $options);

        $activity = $this->TwitterPosts->fetchAll($select)->toArray();

        return $activity;
    }

    public static function prepareOptions($options)
    {
        if(!is_array($options))
        {
            $options = array(); 
        }

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

        if(Zend_Date::isDate($options['start_date']))
        {
            $date = new Zend_Date($options['start_date']);
            $date->setTime('00:00:00');
            $date->setTimezone('UTC');

            $options['start_date'] = $date->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
        }

        if(Zend_Date::isDate($options['end_date']))
        {
            $date = new Zend_Date($options['end_date']);
            $date->setTime('23:59:59');
            $date->setTimezone('UTC');

            $options['end_date'] = $date->toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
        }

        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        $options['mainTerms'] = array();
        if(!empty($options['terms']) && !is_array($options['terms']))
        {
            $options['mainTerms'] = explode(' ', $options['terms']);    
        }

        if(!is_array($options['terms']))
        {
            $options['terms'] = array();
        }

        if($options['group_id'] || $options['client_id'])
        {
            $TwitterSearches = new Model_DbTable_TwitterSearches();

            $options['terms'] = array_merge($TwitterSearches->getList($options),$options['terms']);

            if(empty($options['terms']))
            {
                $options['terms'] = array();
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }

    public static function prepareSelect($select, $options)
    {
        if($options['start_date'])
        {
            $select->where('t.datetime >= ?', $options['start_date']);
        }

        if($options['end_date'])
        {
            $select->where('t.datetime <= ?', $options['end_date']);
        }

        foreach($options['mainTerms'] as $mainTerm)
        {
            $select->where('t.content LIKE ?', "%$mainTerm%");
        }

        if($options['user_id'])
        {
            $select->where("t.user_id = ?", $options['user_id']);
        }

        if($options['terms'])
        {
            $select->where('MATCH (t.content) AGASINT(?)', $options['terms']);
        }

        if($options['rate'])
        {
            if($options['rate'] == 'NotRated')
            {
                $select->where('r.rate IS NULL');
            }
            else
            {
                $select->where('r.rate = ?', $options['rate']);
            }
        }

        if($options['last_update'])
        {
            $select->where('t.created_at > ?', $options['last_update']);
        }

        if($options['max_datetime'])
        {
            $select->where('t.created_at < ?', $options['max_datetime']);
        }

        return $select;
    }
}
```

**The Model:**

```
<?php
class Model_TwitterPost extends Zf_Model
{
    private $_name = 'twitter';

    protected $_properties = array(
        'id', 
        'status_id', 
        'user_id', 
        'content'
    );

    protected $_User = null;

    public function setUser(Zf_Model $User)
    {
        $this->_User = $User;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->_User;
    }

    public function getPermalink()
    {
        return 'http://twitter.com/' . $this->screen_name . '/' . $this->status_id;
    }

    public function hasTerm($term)
    {
        if(preg_match("/\b$term\b/i", $this->getContent()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getEntityName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function getUserProfileLink()
    {
        return $this->getUser()->getProfileLink() . '/status/' . $this->getStatusId();
    }
}
```

**Abstract model (Generic Object):**

```
<?php
abstract class Zf_Model
{
    protected $_properties = array();
    protected $_modified = array();
    protected $_data = array();

    protected $_new = true;
    protected $_loaded = false;

    public function __construct($id=false)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        if(!empty($id))
        {
            $this->_data['id'] = (int)$id;
            $this->setNew(false);
        }
    }

    public function populate($data)
    {
        if(is_array($data) && count($data))
        {
            foreach($data as $k => $v)
            {
                if(in_array($k,$this->_properties))
                {
                    $this->_data[$k] = $v;
                }
            }
        }

        $this->setLoaded(true);
    }

    public function setNew($new=true)
    {
        $this->_new = (bool)$new;
    }

    public function isNew()
    {
        return $this->_new;
    }

    public function setLoaded($loaded = true)
    {
        $this->_loaded = (bool)$loaded;
    }

    public function isLoaded()
    {
        return $this->_loaded;
    }

    public function __call($methodName, $args) {

        if(method_exists($this, $methodName))
        {
            return $this->$methodName($args);
        }

        $property = $methodName;
        if (preg_match('~^(set|get)(.*)$~', $methodName, $matches)) 
        {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_Word_CamelCaseToUnderscore();
            $property = strtolower($filter->filter($matches[2]));

            if(in_array($property, $this->_properties)) 
            {
                if('set' == $matches[1]) 
                {
                    $this->_data[$property] = $args[0];

                    if(true === $this->isLoaded())
                    {
                        $this->_modified[$property] = true;
                    }

                    return $this;
                }
                elseif('get' == $matches[1])
                {
                    if(array_key_exists($property, $this->_data))
                    {
                        return $this->_data[$property];
                    }

                    throw new Exception("The property $property or $methodName() method was not setted for " . get_class($this));
                }
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("The property '$property' doesn't exists.");
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->_data[$key]))
        {
            return $this->_data[$key];
        }
        return $this->$key;
    }

    public function __set($key,$value)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($key,$this->_properties))
        {
            $this->_data[$key] = $value;
            return;
        }

        $this->$key = $value;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return (!$this->_data['id']) ? null : $this->_data['id']; 
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        // If it's a new object
        if(true === $this->isNew())
        {
            return $this->_data;
        }

        // Else, if it's existing object
        $data = array();
        foreach($this->_modified as $k=>$v)
        {
            if($v)
            {
                $data[$k] = $this->_data[$k];
            }
        }

        if(count($data))
        {
            return $data;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function reload()
    {
        $this->_modified = array();
    }
}
```